# divide samples (numbers) into tests (in the form of intervals)

Tags: php, loops, logic, intervals

I am trying to divide samples (numbers) into tests (in the form of intervals). But my results are not correct as per the below required result. The code below is working fine till samples of 20 or less than 20. But if more than 20 samples, the results are wired.

**The result should come with this case :**

If 19 samples - 2 tests:  1-10, 11-19

If 20 samples - 2 tests:  1-10, 11-20

If 21 samples - 3 tests:  1-10, 11-16, 17-21

If 23 samples - 3 tests:  1-10, 11-17, 18-23

If 24 samples - 3 tests:  1-10, 11-17, 18-24

If 31 samples - 4 tests:  1-10, 11-20, 21–26, 27-31.

```
<?php
$samples = 23;
$tests = 1;

if($samples > 10) {
    $tests = ceil($samples/10);
}

echo $tests." tests\n";

$s = 1
for ($x = 0; $x < $tests; $x++) {

    if($samples > 20) {
        $c = $s.'-'.ceil($samples/$tests);
    }
    if($x > 0) {
        $c = (ceil($samples/$tests)+1).'-'.$samples;
    }
    echo $c."\n";
}
?>
```

**Result coming which is wrong:**

3 tests : 1-8, 9-23, 9-23

Comment: What about 29? I could see it being three tests, `1-10, 11-20, 21-29`, or four tests, `1-10, 11-20, 21-25, 26-29`, depending on how the logic is. I get that you are dividing the last group of samples into two tests, and when there's an odd number the first test should contain the extra. (At least, I think that's what I'm seeing.) I think we might need to see a whole series. Also, does the grouping happen below ten, or is that never divided.

Comment: You never adjust where you are, you dont keep track of anything